# Error when trying to upload images to Firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to create an app which allow the user to upload an image and display it in the page with React and Firebase.

this is the part of the code that responsible for the issue:
the image variable is coming from from the state

```
const [image, setImage] = useState("");
const [caption, setCaption] = useState("");
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)

function handleChange (e){
    if  (e.target.files[0]){
        setImage(e.target.files[0]);
    }
}
function handleUpload(){
    const uploadTask =  storage.ref('images/${image.name}').put(image)
    uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
            const progress = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *  100
             );
            setProgress(progress);

           },
           (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            alert(error.message);
            },
            () => {
                storage
                .ref("images")
                .child(image.name)
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then(url => {
                    db.collection("posts").add({
                        timestamp: db.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                        caption : caption,
                        imgUrl: url,
                        userName: username
                    })
                            setProgress(0);
                            setCaption("");
                            setImage(null);
                })
            }

        )
  
}
```

and this error get logged in the console :

```
Uncaught 

FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/invalid-argument", message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.", serverResponse_: null, name_: "FirebaseError"}code_: "storage/invalid-argument"message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File."name_: "FirebaseError"serverResponse_: nullcode: (...)message: (...)name: (...)serverResponse: (...)__proto__: Object
    rethrowCaughtError @ react-dom.development.js:328
    runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3336
    runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3537
    handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3581
    batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21729
    batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:798
    dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:3591
    attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4311
    dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4232
    unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:659
    runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11077
    discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21746
    discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:811
    dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4211
```

I have tried to change `put(image)` to `put(blob)` but it did not work

Comment: The error is complaining about what you're passing to `put()`, but we can't see what is.  All we know is taht you're using a variable called `image`.  Please edit the question to be more clear what's happening, and what you expect to happen instead of this error.

Comment: Ok my co-developer  have edited it is it clear now?

Comment: Not really.  There's still no explanation of what the `image` variable is, or what you expect this code to do other than produce that error.

Comment: I have added the needed details the image variable is coming from the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The line:

```
const uploadTask =  storage.ref('images/${image.name}').put(image)
```

Has an error, it should be using the symbol `` ` `` (backquote/backtick) instead of using single quotes `'`:

```js
const uploadTask =  storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image)
```

otherwise you will create a reference to the literal string `images/${image.name}` instead of `image/value_of_variable_image.jpg` more about Template literals can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

2. You haven't still showed us what's the content of the `image` variable, I can see from the code that you're calling a `setState` inside a function that appears to be a callback, but I'm not seeing from where are you calling, you can do it from a input like this:

```
<input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
```

If you're already using it like that, I recommend to add `console.log(image)` outside of a function in order debug what's the content of the variable before sending it to `put()`. Just as a reference the output from the `console.log(image)` should be an instance of the `File` [javascript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)